# C# Unity проблема с воспроизведением звука и уничтожением эффекта

Tags: c#, unity3d

```
public class GasBottle : MonoBehaviour
{

    public GameObject BangEffectPref;

    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Bullet")
        {
            Collider[] allCollider = Physics.OverlapSphere(transform.position, 5f);
            foreach(var item in allCollider)
            {

                if (item.attachedRigidbody)
                {
                    if (item.GetComponent<BodyPart>())
                    {
                        item.GetComponent<BodyPart>().ThisEnemy.TakeDamage(10000);
                    }
                 /*   else if (item.GetComponent<PlayerHealth>())
                    {
                        item.GetComponent<PlayerHealth>().TakeDamage(10000);
                    }
                */
                    Vector3 direction = (item.transform.position - transform.position).normalized;

                    item.attachedRigidbody.AddForce( direction * 2000);
                    
                }
            }
            Instantiate(BangEffectPref, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
            GetComponent<AudioSource>().Play();
            Destroy(BangEffectPref);
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

Вот код моей газовой бочке, которая взрывается при попадании в нее пули. Есть две проблемы

1. Звук взрыва не воспроизводится (Can not play a disabled audio source) (хотя audiosource включен)
2. Эффект взрыва не удаляется в иерархии, он остается, хоть и невидим, но в целях оптимизации хочется его убрать (Destroying assets is not permitted to avoid data loss

Answer (score 2):

1 Было бы странно, если бы мёртвые котята мяукали. Вот тут тоже самое.

```
gameObject.GetComponent<AudioSource>().Play();
Destroy(gameObject);
```

2 Ну так и удаляй эффект а не...

```
public GameObject BangEffectPref;
...
Destroy(BangEffectPref);
```

Answer (score -3):

Ты можешь использовать `PlayOneShot` к компоненту AudioSource. Таким образом ничего удалять или отключать не придётся.

Касательно первой ошибки: получая ссылку на AudioSource, попробуй включить этот компонент: используй `GetComponent<AudioSource>().enabled = true`;